# Create tags subfolder on 11ty

Tags: eleventy

I have my blog posts containing the tags property:

```js
tags: web design
```

How do I make sure that 11ty creates a subfolder in `/blog/tags/` for each of the existing tags containing the list of blog posts using that tag?

For example:

```js
/blog/tags/web/index.html containing

    - how to make websites
    - how to use CSS

/blog/tags/design/index.html containing

    - The difference between UI and UX
    - Create nice modals
```

So far I've created a layout inside `_includes/layouts/tag.html` but it doesn't seem to have any effect:

```js
---
pagination:
  enabled: true
  size: 9
  data: collections.tags

layout: default
permalink: /blog/tag/{{ tag | slugify }}
---

<h1>Tag {{ tag }}</h1>
```

Is this even possible on 11ty out-of-the-box?

I was reading [this tutorial](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/quicktips/tag-pages/) but it's so vague.
It doesn't specify where to put the template, how to name it, how to tell 11ty to use it for tags etc.